# Count messages from kafka topic all hour

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I would like to count messages coming from kakfa topic.

For example I have this case class:

```
case class Message(timestamp: LocalDateTime)
```

I receive message of this class, and I would like to count how many message I have within in 1 hour. Let suppose message are ordered in this topic (timestamp corresponds to when the message enter in the topic).

I would like to create a case class like this:

```
case class Counter(datetime: LocalDateTime, count: Int)
```

Let say I have 100 messages the first hour, then 150 I will have:

```
Counter("2018-05-17 00:00:00", 100)
Counter("2018-05-17 00:01:00", 150)
```

Any idea on how to that ? For information I can't/don't want to use kafka-streams.

Thanks!

EDIT:

My source is a kafka topic which I would like to use with the Consumer API. My sink is a postgresql table.

Comment: would you use Akka Streams Kafka?

Comment: I really don't know this framework, but if this is "just" a library I am ready to hear about it if you think this is better than kafka only

Comment: Actually usage of the streams depends on your source and sink so if your source and sink both are kafka then use kafka stream if it’s something else then Akka stream would be better.

Comment: So you want to know the number of messages on the consumer side?

Comment: How do you intend to consume the messages from the topic, using the consumer API?

Comment: Yes, my source is a kafka topic which I would like to consumer with the consumer API. Each Counter element will be written into a postgresql table.

Comment: @Thomas before windowing operation introduced, all time based aggregation operation was applied as you mentioned. So you can round down each date field when you consume message, and increment count for it. You can store this information in Map<String,Integer>. You don't need to additional class for it. There is  a just one important point that is you must store this count between defined interval(each 1 minute) to your table because you will lose aggregated value in case of any failure(in-memory data will be released).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out a solution with `Flink`.

I read some documentation about time window in Flink and this [page](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/event_timestamp_extractors.html#assigners-with-ascending-timestamps) talks about ascending timestamp in a topic (which is is my case).

So here a solution :

```
  val inputStream: DataStream[Message] = env.addSource(kafkaConsumer)
  val timedStream: DataStream[Message] = inputStream
    .assignAscendingTimestamps(_.timestamp)
  val timeWindow = timedStream.timeWindowAll(Time.minutes(1)).sum(1)
```

It counts all elements within a tumbling window of 1 minute.

For a more specific solution and arrive at `Counter("2018-05-17 00:00:00", 100)` we have to extends `AllWindowFunction`:

```
  class CustomWindowFunction extends AllWindowFunction[Message, Counter, TimeWindow] {
  def apply(window: TimeWindow, input: Iterable[Message], out: Collector[Counter]): Unit = {
    out.collect(
      Counter(
        new LocalDateTime(window.getStart),
        input.size
      )
    )
  }
}
```

And then apply it to our timeStream:

```
  val inputStream: DataStream[MyClass] = env.addSource(kafkaConsumer)
  val timedStream: DataStream[MyClass] = inputStream
    .assignAscendingTimestamps(_.timestamp)
  val timeWindow = timedStream.timeWindowAll(Time.minutes(1)).apply(new CustomWindowFunction())
```

If in our topic in input we have the `Message` Class we obtain the `Counter` Class at the end.

This is the "better" solution I found for now.

Answer (score 1):

The solution you want is usually called *windowing* in stream processing terms, and most stream processing libraries have this as a feature. There's [a good writeup](https://softwaremill.com/windowing-in-big-data-streams-spark-flink-kafka-akka/) by Software Mill comparing Spark Streaming, Flink, Kafka Streams, and Akka Streams.

You could attempt to implement it yourself, but the libraries mentioned above are all battle tested and have simple, readable APIs. If you don't want to use Kafka Streams, then [Akka Streams Kafka](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-kafka/current/home.html) mentioned in one of the comments (part of the [Alpakka project](https://github.com/akka/alpakka)) would be worth considering.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know where I could find some example to start ? For Flink it will be top, I already use a job Flink in my pipeline.